# NHibernate - reference without (always) doing SQL join

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I've got a question that may reek of code/design stink but I'm going to ask it anyway.

Say I've got the two trivial classes below:

```
public class PostOffice
{
    public virtual string ZipCode {get; set;}
    public virtual string StreetAddress {get; set;}
}

public class Person
{
    public virtual in ID {get; protected set;}
    public virtual string FirstName {get; set;}
    public virtual string LastName {get; set;}
    public virtual PostOffice ZipCode {get; set;}
}
```

and I've used FluentNHibernate to set PostOffice.ZipCode as the ID and provided the mapping override below:

```
model.Override<Person>(p=> p.References( z=> z.ZipCode, "ZipCode"));
```

Person.ZipCode in the database is just a VARCHAR and I would normally write some SQL like

```
SELECT * 
FROM Person 
WHERE ZipCode = '90210'
```

but if I have an NHibernate session and do something like the following:

```
session.Query<Person>().Where(p=>p.ZipCode == '90210')
```

the resulting SQL (pretty-printed) looks like

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM Person p INNER JOIN PostOffice o 
    ON p.ZipCode = o.ZipCode 
WHERE o.ZipCode = '90210'
```

My question - if entities are lazy-load by default, is it possible to specify some mapping properties such that NHibernate will generate the SQL **without** the join?  The example is trivial but in my actual situation, the table being joined to has millions of rows so I'd like to avoid the join if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If the fields `ZipCode` and `StreetAddress` are actually in the `Person` table then you need to map `PostOffice` as a `Component` and not a `Reference`.

http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto_mapping#Components

#### Edit:

You may be able to map a separate property to just that ZipCode field.

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual in ID {get; protected set;}
    public virtual string FirstName {get; set;}
    public virtual string LastName {get; set;}
    public virtual string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public virtual PostOffice PostOffice {get; set;}
}

model.Override<Person>(p=> 
    p.References( z=> z.PostOffice, "ZipCode")
     .Not.Update()
     .Not.Insert()
);
```

Comment: Not in my actual case, no.  For my real situation, ZipCode is the only shared column and the PostOffice table has another 80 or so columns (legacy structure...)